# rendering pie chart in side bar for AppScript add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I want to render a pie chart on the side bar for an AppScript add-on I am developing for Google Spreadsheets.

I want to generate the pie chart using Google Charts.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite a lazy question, as a quick Google search returns: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-pie-chart-builder.

Comment: Anyone can embedded pie chart builder. The side bar is a sandboxed environment. The question is will it work ? I have tried embedding google maps and it did not work.

Comment: If we're talking about the same sidebar @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars, then I don't see why it wouldn't, it's just an embedded HTML page. Never tried though.